# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Worked last night now its not working

Tags: java, servlets, dao

Basically I have a DAO class where im loading stuff from a database, it's called FilmDAO, in FilmoviServlet I am calling FilmDAO.getAll() function which fills an array with data from database. What is funny is that this worked perfectly last night and now Im getting this error. 0 logic.

Error code:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet FilmoviServlet threw exception
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: baza.FilmDAO
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1698)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1544)
>       at aplikacija.FilmoviServlet.doGet(FilmoviServlet.java:21)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:610)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:503)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: If class has not been deleted then try rebuild your application and run the application again.